# Is it possible to manage indirect .h dependencies with 'touch' command?

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies, c-header

It is advised to use `-MM` option to manage indirect dependencies in headers. Why we don't use `touch` command. Am I missing anything here, or just it's because it's a hack and we want to keep the real last modification of timestamp (look like intrusive method).

Example:
- stack.h, stack.c, array.h, array.c
array depend on stack

```
array.o: array.c

array.c: array.h

stack.o: stack.c

stack.c: stack.h

stack.h: array.h
    touch stack.h
```

Another thing: files need to be entirely reparsed each time with `-MM` option, right ? And not with this `touch` method and be an advantage if I don't miss anything, no ?

Comment: Yes, `touch` is a horrible hack that I (for one) would never use, but afaik it'd work, if you don't care about preserving modtimes.  (It's a hack because it subverts the philosophy of `make`: header files *don't* depend on each other in the way that object files depend on source files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `touch`.  But it's painful for anything but relatively trivial environments, because you have to ensure that your header file include dependencies are accurately reflected in the makefile otherwise you can get build failures or worse, mysterious crashes.

Regarding *files need to be entirely reparsed each time*, you should look into the [modern auto-dependency generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) methods.  These do the dependency generation as a *side-effect* of the compilation, so it doesn't cost anything extra.